# PHP script to deliver latest version of a file

Tags: php

My PHP's rusty and I'm hoping that someone can help me with a quick script - I don't really know where to start with it!

I have a folder containing zipped archives of various versions of a software product:

- Product_1.00.zip
- Product_1.05.zip
- Product_2.00.zip

etc.

Now, on my web site I have a button to download the product. However, I'd like that button to always download the latest version.

It seems to me that a nice solution would be to link to a PHP script that would scan the folder for the latest version and deliver that file to the user as if they have pointed the browser directly at the file.

Can anyone provide me with a starting point?

Comment: How do you identify the latest version of the file; or is it the highest version numer?

Comment: Yes, highest version number.

Comment: Have you tried [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)?

Comment: I can divide the problem in to three parts - How to list the files, how to parse the file names and compare the numbers and how to deliver the file to the user. I could do this in 15 minutes in Objective C, but in PHP some example code to get me on the way would really help, otherwise I can see myself losing a day...

Comment: USe glob() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with a wildcard for the version number part of the filename; then a natural sort descending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the easiest to read the files from the directory into an array. Then `natsort` the array and pop off the last entry.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
function getLatestVersion() {
    $dir = dir('.');
    $files = array();

    while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false) {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
    $dir->close();

    natsort($files);
    return array_pop($files);
}
```

Outputs

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "."
  [1]=>
  string(2) ".."
  [2]=>
  string(16) "Product_1.00.zip"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "Product_1.05.zip"
  [5]=>
  string(16) "Product_2.00.zip"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "Product_10.00.zip"
}
```

### How to download the latest version of the zip file?

**EDIT**

Like @j_mcnally pointed out in his comment below it's more efficient to let the webserver handle the serving of static files. Possible ways are direct links or redirecting the request from the PHP file to the right location using a `301`.

But if you still want to let PHP do the work. Here is an example.

---

*Grabbed the example below from http://perishablepress.com/http-headers-file-downloads and altered it a bit.*

```
<?php // HTTP Headers for ZIP File Downloads
// http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/11/17/http-headers-file-downloads/

// set example variables

// Only this line is altered
$filename = getLatestVersion();

$filepath = "/var/www/domain/httpdocs/download/path/";

// http headers for zip downloads
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($filepath.$filename);
?>
```

Comment: Ah. Because by changing the filename (by including the version) I can deliver the download via a CDN and rest assured that users will always pick up the latest version.

Comment: Hi. Ah, yes, natsort looks like an interesting solution, there's no parsing whatsoever! That's just the sort of reason that I wanted to ask on here first for, rather than muddle through! Thanks. Now, I don't suppose you know how to solve the last aspect of the request - actually delivering the file back to the user when they point their browser at it?

Comment: I wrapped it into a function and added a link sample for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: On a sidenote. Never trust the mtime of a file to tell you it's the latest version.

Comment: Hi, sorry we're getting our wires crossed. What I'd like to so is create a file called Product.php that I can link to from anywhere to download the underlying zip file (<a href=".../Product.php">). The PHP script would then deliver the content of the file as if you'd linked directly to the original.

Comment: Why the gymnastics? use a 301, why make php do the work of serving/streaming the file? i would upvote if not for that. let your webserver do what is is optimized for... serving.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more complete and correct like @j_mcnally pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Of course, more checks can be added depending on what else can be stored in that folder; you may also change the way of reading the folder content if it contains too many files, etc.
Keyword in this code is probably [`strnatcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) for strings comparison.

```
<?php
$files = scandir('/path/to/files');
$result = array_reduce(
    $files,
    function($a, $b) {
        $tpl = '/^Product_(.+).zip$/';
        // return second file name if the first file doesn't follow pattern Product_XXX.zip
        if (!preg_match($tpl, $a)) {
            return $b;
        }
        // return first file name if the second file doesn't follow pattern Product_XXX.zip
        if (!preg_match($tpl, $b)) {
            return $a;
        }
        return strnatcmp($a, $b) >= 0 ? $a : $b;
    },
    ''
);
```

Comment: seems legit... do you need to cast to an integer or is that assumed by >= 0? i forget how to php. My only concern is that 11 is > 2 but 2 before 1 might mess sorting up in the case of 11.0 vs 2.0

Comment: `strnatcmp()` is exactly for 'natural' sorting. So it compares strings, but when it finds numeric characters it compares them as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The below will look within the `downloads` directory, find the latest file (by looking at the modify time of the files) and return the name of the newest file:

```
$dir = dir("downloads");
$files = array();
while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false) {
    $files[filemtime($file)] = $file;
}
$dir->close();

ksort($files);
$fileToDownload = $files[0];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `filemtime` is a bit tricky I guess. Why not `natsort` an array of filenames?

Comment: @bart Product_2.00.zip > Product_10.00.zip

Answer (score 0):

This code works by using the file modification time to determine the latest version in the given directory, perhaps using regular expressions on the file names would be a better approach, however this demonstraits PHP's DirectoryIterator.

```
$files = array();

foreach(new DirectoryIterator("productZips/") as $fileInfo) {

  if(!$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
  $files[$fileInfo->getMTime()] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}

ksort($files);
$latestFile = array_pop($files);
```

You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php